# Python - Unique Lists

Tags: python, list, set, unique

I have a list of lists.  I want to get all unique lists based on just the first three elements.  If there are duplicates, then it should just return the last item.  So for instance based on this

```
[['one', 'two', 'three', 'teennn'], ['five', 'five', 'five', 'five'],
 ['seven', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]
```

I want to return this

```
[['five', 'five', 'five', 'five'],
 ['seven', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]
```

Comment: Can you explain your goal a little better or provide the code you have?

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = [['one', 'two', 'three', 'teennn'], 
       ['five', 'five', 'five', 'five'], 
       ['seven', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven'], 
       ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]
output = []
seen = set()
lst.reverse()
for item in lst:
    if not item[:3] in seen:
        output.append(item)
        seen.add(item[:3])
output.reverse()
```

This ensures that the first three items are always unique. Starting from the end of your list `lst`, using `reverse`, ensures that the last appearance of each starting set is included.

Comment: Assuming memory isn't an issue, it's worth using a `set` to keep track of the seen tuples to bring the time complexity down from O(n^2) to O(n).

Answer (score 3):

If order isn't important, then you can use a `dict`:

```
data = [['one', 'two', 'three', 'teennn'], ['five', 'five', 'five', 'five'], ['seven', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]
new = {tuple(el[:3]): el for el in data}.values()
# [['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], ['seven', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven'], ['five', 'five', 'five', 'five']]
```

Or, if you really wanted to maintain order, then something like:

```
new = [data[idx] for idx in sorted({tuple(el[:3]): idx for idx, el in enumerate(data)}.values())]
```